# OpenWrt Hostapd compilation issue

Tags: compiling, hostapd

I am struggling to compile OpenWrt. I get stuck when trying to compile Hostapd.

I am trying to install to build an OS on wireless access points (Brand: Open Mesh). I am using OpenWRT to perform that following [this tutorial](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/buildroot.exigence). But when I arrive at the compilation step with the `make` command I got the messages listed below then the compilation get aborted.

Host: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. I got OpenWrt by issuing this command:

```
git clone https://git.openwrt.org/openwrt.git
```

Error messages:

```
Cloning into 'hostapd-2016-01-15'
fatal: unable to connect to w1.fi
w1.fi: Name or service not known
```

See the compilation issue with the following link:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/17486118/

Please, can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. I am trying to install to build an OS on wireless access points (Brand: Open Mesh). I am using OpenWRT to perform that following this tutorial [link]https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/buildroot.exigence[/link]. But when I arrive at the compilation step with the make command I got the messages listed above then the compilation get aborted. "Cloning into 'hostapd-2016-01-15' fatal: unable to connect to w1.fi w1.fi: Name or service not known" . I hope it is clearer.

Comment: Ubuntu release: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.  For OPenWrt I just run the command "git clone https : //git.openwrt.org/openwrt.git" .  Then I follow the instructions of the tutorial in the previous link.  After make menuconfig, I compile with make and later I got the above error.

Comment: Updated the question. I'm voting to reopen the question , better if  you upload full compile log to http://paste.ubuntu.com then [edit] the question and add the link.

Comment: This question is not Ubuntu related. The problem must be with the hostapd git repo. I suggest asking at OpenWrt forums or report a bug to their tracker.

Comment: @Lucid, If you didn't resolve yet, I just tried it and it works fine. The error you get that could not fetch some source module, due a network issue (may be a proxy). Also I could confirm that mirror server `w1.fi[0: 212.71.239.96]`, have some unreliable service, may be it is working under heavy load, see my ping check https://paste.ubuntu.com/23557555/ . What I could say, just try in different time  in the day/night, after you confirm the ping goes well.